# Why does transform.forward when equal to 0 when multiplied not equal to 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, transform, zero

Im making movement for my camera in unity. The starting position for my camera is 0,0,0. When i press the W key the code i take the current position and multiply it by a movement speed and equal it to another vector 3 to then update the postion of the position of the camera. It works great but i cant understand why when i think about.

If my camera is initialised at 0,0,0 then why does transform.forward * movementSpeed not always eqaul 0?
This is the same for all directions i just used W as an example

Any help would be greatly appreciated as im new to unity. Thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 newPosition;
    [SerializeField] private float movementSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float movementTime;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        newPosition = transform.position; 

        Debug.Log(transform.position); //prints 0.0,0.0,0.0
        Debug.Log(transform.forward * movementSpeed); //prints 0.0,0.0,0.3
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        handleKeyboardInput();
    }

    void handleKeyboardInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            newPosition += (transform.forward * movementSpeed);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            newPosition += (transform.right * -movementSpeed);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            newPosition += (transform.forward * -movementSpeed);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            newPosition += (transform.right * movementSpeed);
        }
        
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, Time.deltaTime * movementTime);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code works is becuase `transform.forward` and `transform.right` refer to the forward and right directions of you player. When you add `transform.forward * speed` to your `newPosition`, you are adding the forward direction of the player but with a magnitude (length) of your speed.

If you want to try to understand it better, you can use `print(transform.forward)` or `print(transform.forward * speed)` or do `Debug.drawRay(transform.position, transform.forward)`

Comment: Thankyou very much cleared up my issue. I was thinking transform.forward refered to a coordinate that changed depedning on the position of the camera rather than a constant value so i was even expecting it to speed up the further from the centre of the world i was.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is multiplying [transform.forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html)(0,0,1) or [transform.right](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html), both of them are not zero vectors, instead they represent the specified direction.

Answer (score 0):

`Vector3.forward` is (0,0,1) if you want zero use `Vector3.zero`.